# What does zip in this code?

Tags: python, zip

It's a beginner's question of python zip. 
I am now doing udacity deep learning assignment LSTM. 
There is a line of code which I don't understand how it works.

```
s = [''.join(x) for x in zip(s, characters(b))]
```

It is copied from the context below.

```
def batches2string(batches):
    """Convert a sequence of batches back into their (most likely) string
    representation."""
    s = [''] * batches[0].shape[0]
    for b in batches:
        s = [''.join(x) for x in zip(s, characters(b))]
    return s
```

I try to rewrite it in for loop, but it seems I am not doing properly. Can someone help me how to rewrite it in for loop?

```
s1 = [''] * batches[0].shape[0]
for b in batches:
    for x in zip(s1, characters(b)):
        print(x)
        s1.append(x)
        print(s1)
```

Comment: batches itself is a list, contains several 2-dim np.array. Let's say len(batches) = 11, batches[0].shape=(64, 27)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x` in the loop matches a `tuple`.

Another syntax is `for a,b in zip` but here it's simpler to have a tuple to pass to `join`. Equivalent in your loop to:

```
s1.append("".join(x))
```

which is slightly overkill here if you ask me since you have only 2 values to `join`. Another way would be:

```
for a,b in zip(s1, characters(b)):
    s1.append(a+b)
```

and for comprehension:

```
s = [a+b for a,b in zip(s, characters(b))]
```

`join` isn't faster in that case since we only have 2 terms to add without any separator and `join` is a function call.

EDIT: now I'm curious, and I'm benching this:

```
l = ["foo","bar","spam","egg""hello","world"]

start = time.time()

for _ in range(10000000):
    s = [a+b for a,b in zip(l,l)]

end = time.time()
print("elapsed {}".format(end-start))
```

runs in `14.80` seconds.

now replace by:

```
s = ["".join(x) for x in zip(l,l)]
```

and it runs in `17.75` seconds. So for once `+` wins... `join` is helpful to avoid the quadratic effect of summing strings, that is if there are more than 2 strings to sum...

Don't use `join` here, use it when you have more than 2 values to join and/or a separator in between.